# PHP json_encode returns null value from unicode character

Tags: php, json

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [BookDateID] => 4
    [HotelName] => Adams’ Inn
)
```

**Output:**

```
{"BookDateID":"4","HotelName":null}
```

Any magic?

**BTW,** I have an alternative solution by looping thru each array and have them mb_convert_encoding(str,'HTML-ENTITIES') but I want the character remains the same as I have to insert this into a DB.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $array[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value,'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

Comment: Your PHP file may not be in the "correct" encoding: http://3v4l.org/ipQuW

Comment: @Passerby what do you mean by that? Do I need to set some encoding on my php.ini or just ini_set()? Something like default_charset?

Comment: This may not be some configuration problem; it's your PHP _file_'s encoding that may matters. Check your PHP file's encoding with some editor (Notepad2, Notepad++, etc.) and make sure it's UTF-8.

Comment: @Passerby I'm using sublime. I am pretty sure I am in correct file encoding from my text editor.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding` by default uses `mb_internal_encoding` as source encoding, which by default is `ISO-8859-1`. Try `mb_detect_encoding($array["HotelName"],"UTF-8, ISO-8859-1")` (or add other encoding according to your location) to see if the string is actually in UTF-8.

Comment: Or better, modify your alternative solution to `mb_convert_encoding($value,"UTF-8");` and see if it works.

Comment: @Passerby my alternative solution works fine. I mean, from my question I don't want to use that mb_convert_encoding. BTW, your suggestion about `mb_convert_encoding($value,"UTF-8")` that will make `’` into `?`.

Comment: Then I would suggest: 1) Update your question with your `mb_internal_encoding()` and `mb_detect_order()` output; 2) Update your question with your encoded array value (and encoded JSON string); or 3) Chop down your code to a minimum version that can still reproduce the problem and upload to somewhere that other can fetch.

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` needs UTF-8 encoded data. Make sure the data is UTF-8 encoded; currently it's likely Latin-1 encoded. How to do this depends on where the data comes from. Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: I tried ini_set('default_charset','utf-8') but `’` becomes `?`. Anyway, my alternative solutions looks good but would be better if I don't have to `mb_convert_encoding()` encase there's no `mbstring` installed.

Comment: That ini setting by itself doesn't do much. What encoding is your data in? If you can't answer that, read the beforelinked articles again.