# json_encode() returns null since array has huge number of records

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have used `json_encode($response)` to list the all the files in the directory. Since it has nearly 8000 records in the array of `$response`, when displayed in the page, it returns `null`.

I have research about this issue. So far, I could not find any solution.

This is my code:

```
$response['content'] = Files::$output;
echo json_encode($response);
Files::$output` /* this will return the list of files in the html format. */
```

When I try `echo json_last_error_msg();`, it returns:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: How are you displaying it on the page, can you post your code?

Comment: have you try to change the memory_limit parameter in php.ini ?

Comment: In my php.ini i have set memory limit 128M

Comment: How exactly have you concluded that the issue is the *size* of the input and not something else? Have you checked `json_last_error_msg`?

Comment: No, as i research about this issue, i have concluded its something like that.

Comment: I recommend you try `echo json_last_error_msg()` or `echo json_last_error()` after the failed encode before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: when i try it echo  it shows Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: So your problem turns out to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868096/php-json-encode-returns-null-value-from-unicode-character/14869080#14869080

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80372/discussion-between-jagadeesh-and-deceze).

Answer (score 0):

JSON can only accept valid UTF characters when encoding them via `json_encode`.

Odds are, you have malformed input (as your error message says), which is more than likely some variant of a windows code page.

To ensure that your array is free of invalid JSON data, you can either convert it at a database layer (assuming you are using a database), or do the following (this assumes you have malformed `latin1`/`ISO-8859-1` as the cause of your bad data):

```
foreach ($row as $key => &$value) {
    if ( ! mb_check_encoding($value, "UTF-8")) {
        // assume base is latin1; your mileage may vary
        $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");
    }
}
```

You can't really force `json_encode` to parse your invalid data, so you're going to have to massage your dataset into valid UTF-8.